# React Hook Form V7 - Material UI 5 Autocomplete: Lazy loaded values not validated

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I use react-hook-form V7 with an Material UI 5 Autocomplete input. My lazy loaded values in the Autocomplete are not validated on first submit click (but on second). What's wrong?

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    setItemList([
      { id: 1, name: "item1" },
      { id: 2, name: "item2" }
    ]);
    setItemIdSelected(2);
  }, []);

  [...]

  <Autocomplete
    options={itemList}
    getOptionLabel={(item) => (item.name ? item.name : "")}
    getOptionSelected={(option, value) =>
      value === undefined || value === "" || option.id === value.id
    }
    value={
      itemIdSelected
        ? itemList.find((item) => item.id === itemIdSelected)
        : ""
    }
    onChange={(event, items) => {
      if (items !== null) {
        setItemIdSelected(items.id);
      }
    }}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField
        {...params}
        {...itemsIdFormHookRest}
        label="items"
        margin="normal"
        variant="outlined"
        inputRef={itemsIdFormHookRef}
        error={errors.itemsId ? true : false}
        helperText={errors.itemsId && "item required"}
        required
      />
    )}
  />
  
[...]
```

Please have a look to the code on code sandbox:

[image: Edit React Hook Form V7 - Material UI 5 - lazy loaded values not validated in Autocomplete]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should wrap the Material UI `Autocomplete` with the `Controller` Component provided by React Hook Form. See this [section](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#IntegratingwithUIlibraries) in the documentation for further information.

I would also suggest to remove the `useState` saving the `id`, as you could also access the value via React Hook Form either through `getValues` or after the `handleSubmit` callback is called.

Here is the updated [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v7-material-ui-5-lazy-loaded-values-not-validated-in-autocomplete-forked-h7ugr?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 0):

How can i implement datepickers?
This works only with modal, but when typing yourself is not working.

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns} locale={ruLocale}>
  <Controller
    render={({ field }) => (
      <DatePicker
        value={field.value}
        onChange={(value) => field.onChange(value)}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField {...params} />
        )}
      />
    )}
    name={name}
    control={control}
  />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

I handle react-hook-form with mui Autocomplete in the following way

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.3",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.33.1",
}
```

```
const Country = [{ label: 'United Kingdem', value: 'uk' }];

<Controller
    name={"country"}
    control={control}
    rules={{
        required: true,
    }}
    render={({ field: { onChange, ..._field } }) => (
        <Autocomplete
            options={Country}
            onChange={(_, data) => onChange(data.value)}
            renderInput={(params) => {
                return (
                    <TextField
                        {...params}
                        label="disableCloseOnSelect"
                        variant="standard"
                    />
                );
            }}
            {..._field}
        />
    )}
/>
```