# @mui v5 Autocomplete with React Hook Form 7 not working?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm working on implementing React Hook Form 7. I have many regular TextFields working, however I am now running in to an issue building out an Autocomplete component. Currently, the dropdown toggle button doesn't display, and none of the options are being rendered in the dropdown list. It acts like a regular TextField. I've looked at many other related S.O. posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67132306/react-hook-form-v7-material-ui-5-autocomplete-lazy-loaded-values-not-validate), but none seem to be fixing my issue.

```jsx
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import { validationSchema } from './validationSchema';
import { states, countries } from 'helpers';

const StepTwo: React.FC<Props> = ({ handleNextStep, handlePrevStep }) => {
  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
    mode: 'onBlur',
    reValidateMode: 'onBlur',
    defaultValues: {
      state: null,
      country: null,
    },
  });

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleStepSubmit)} noValidate>
      <Grid item xs={12} className="text-center">
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name="state"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <Autocomplete
              {...field}
              autoComplete
              forcePopupIcon={true}
              fullWidth
              options={states}
              isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option === value}
              renderInput={params => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  error={!!errors?.state}
                  helperText={errors?.state?.message}
                  label="State (Optional)"
                  variant="outlined"
                  size="small"
                  InputProps={{
                    startAdornment: (
                      <InputAdornment position="start">
                        <LocationOnIcon
                          color={errors?.state ? 'error' : 'inherit'}
                        />
                      </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                  }}
                />
              )}
            />
          )}
        />
      </Grid>
      {/* Country Select */}
      <Grid item xs={12} className="text-center">
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name="country"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <Autocomplete
              {...field}
              fullWidth
              options={countries}
              getOptionLabel={item => item}
              isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option === value}
              renderInput={(params: AutocompleteRenderInputParams) => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  error={!!errors?.country}
                  helperText={errors?.country?.message}
                  label="Country (Optional)"
                  variant="outlined"
                  size="small"
                  InputProps={{
                    startAdornment: (
                      <InputAdornment position="start">
                        <PublicIcon
                          color={errors?.country ? 'error' : 'inherit'}
                        />
                      </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                  }}
                />
              )}
            />
          )}
        />
      </Grid>
    </form>
}
```

`states.ts` and `countries.ts` are just arrays of strings with the state and country names. There are no errors in the console. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing to spread the `InputProps`, so basically you're overwriting all the default properties of your `InputProps`.

The function signature of the `onChange` prop of `<Autocomplete />` is slightly different. The actual `value` is the second parameter. Check [here](https://mui.com/api/autocomplete/) for more infos.

```js
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="country"
  render={({ field: { ref, onChange, ...field } }) => (
    <Autocomplete
      {...field}
      onChange={(e, v) => onChange(v)}
      fullWidth
      options={countries}
      isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option === value}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          inputRef={ref}
          error={!!errors?.country}
          helperText={errors?.country?.message}
          label="Country (Optional)"
          variant="outlined"
          size="small"
          InputProps={{
            ...params.InputProps,
            startAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position="start"></InputAdornment>
            )
          }}
        />
      )}
    />
  )}
/>
```

[image: Edit ComboBox Material Demo (forked)]

Comment: Genius, thanks a ton! I'm noticing that if you type in the Autocomplete and make a selection, it returns a "0" rather than the selection, but I imagine I just need to add the `getOptionLabel` prop?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I updated my answer and CodeSandbox.

Comment: You should also pass the `ref` of the `<Controller />` `render` callback to your `<TextField />` `inputRef` prop - this way the field can be automatically focused upon an error. I updated the CodeSandbox and answer and added a required rule for your first input to demo this use case.

Comment: Ooh nice, didn't know about that feature. Thanks for your help!